# Update an array element with inc mongo update

Tags: mongodb, update, array

HI All I have this Data in mongo,

```
{"articleId" : [
            {
                    "articleId" : "9514666",
                    "articleCount" : 1
            }
    ],

    "count" : NumberLong(1),
    "timeStamp" : NumberLong("1416634200000"),
    "interval" : 1,
    "tags" : "famous"
 }
```

I want to update it using this new data

```
 {"articleId" : [      
            {
                    "articleId" : "9514666",
                    "articleCount" : 3
            }
            {
                    "articleId" : "9514667",
                    "articleCount" : 3
            }
    ],

    "count" : NumberLong(6),
    "timeStamp" : NumberLong("1416634200000"),
    "interval" : 1,
    "tags" : "famous"
 }
```

What i need in the output is

```
{"articleId" : [
            {
                    "articleId" : "9514666",
                    "articleCount" : 4
            }
            {
                    "articleId" : "9514667",
                    "articleCount" : 3
            }
    ],

    "count" : NumberLong(7),
    "timeStamp" : NumberLong("1416634200000"),
    "interval" : 1,
    "tags" : "famous"
 }
```

Could you please suggest me how can i achieve this this using update operation
My update query will have **tags** field as query parameter.

Comment: I would suggest posting this to stackoverflow. It is a better forum for development questions.

Comment: @JamesWahlin i posted it here as i thought it could be done by some mongo operation

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished it with your criteria which was to use the tags field in your query. I of course had to filter on the document further to only update that specific document. 
I presumed other documents may have a tag of "famous". I created two documents with tags:famous to prove this worked when updating 1 document. Here's my solution with comments.

```
//basics 
db = test
collection = test

//data looked like this with two documents for testing
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5498778567bbbc2fff723515"),
    "articleId" : [ 
        {
            "articleId" : "9514666",
            "articleCount" : 1
        }
    ],
    "count" : 1,
    "timeStamp" : "1416634200000",
    "interval" : 1,
    "tags" : "famous"
}

/* 1 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5498781567bbbc2fff723516"),
"articleId" : [ 
    {
        "articleId" : "951466622",
        "articleCount" : 22
    }
],
"count" : 1,
"timeStamp" : "1416634200000",
"interval" : 1,
"tags" : "famous"
}


//confirmed I can query the one document like this
db.test.find({'tags': 'famous','articleId.articleId':'9514666'})

//was able to execute an update as described
db.test.update({'tags': 'famous','articleId.articleId':'9514666'}, {"articleId" : [
        {
                "articleId" : "9514666",
                "articleCount" : 4
        },
        {
                "articleId" : "9514667",
                "articleCount" : 3
        }
],

"count" : 7,
"timeStamp" : "1416634200000",
"interval" : 1,
"tags" : "famous"
}) 


//Resulting update to document is
/* 0 */
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5498778567bbbc2fff723515"),
 "articleId" : [ 
    {
        "articleId" : "9514666",
        "articleCount" : 4
    }, 
    {
        "articleId" : "9514667",
        "articleCount" : 3
    }
],
"count" : 7,
"timeStamp" : "1416634200000",
"interval" : 1,
"tags" : "famous"
}

//showing both documents, only first one updated obviously
/* 0 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5498778567bbbc2fff723515"),
"articleId" : [ 
    {
        "articleId" : "9514666",
        "articleCount" : 4
    }, 
    {
        "articleId" : "9514667",
        "articleCount" : 3
    }
],
"count" : 7,
"timeStamp" : "1416634200000",
"interval" : 1,
"tags" : "famous"
}

/* 1 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5498781567bbbc2fff723516"),
"articleId" : [ 
    {
        "articleId" : "951466622",
        "articleCount" : 22
    }
],
"count" : 1,
"timeStamp" : "1416634200000",
"interval" : 1,
"tags" : "famous"
}
```